# extract line from file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

a file I need to extract info from looks like

```
2       41620   .       T       G       100     PASS    AC=3;AF=0.000599042;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=18872;EAS_AF=0;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.0031;AA=.|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000184731|ENST00000327669|Transcript|missense_variant|954|954|318|K/N|aaA/aaC|||-1|tolerated(0.47)|benign(0)||||;GENCODE=ENST00000327669
```

the output I need would be

```
2   41620   CSQ=G    missense_variant
```

the major fields are always divided by ||| but not that the 2 41620 is from the first field and the CSQ=G and missense variant is from the next. It does neither have to be missense_variant nor somethign along the lines but it is always the first and fourth field after the first |||.

How to achieve in perl , awk, sed or so?

Comment: Does whatever you seek to output always going to be in the same columns in the original ? If so, awk is the way to go here

Comment: Writing answer, will post in a minute

Comment: Answer posted. I'm off to sleep, as it's almost 1 am. Let me know if my answer helps and leave upvote if you like it.

Comment: What's up ? I'm still here

Answer (score -1):

Since you've mentioned that data is always in the same columns, AWK is appropriate for this task. However small thing is that You have data that is up to certain point has space as separator , but then switches to using vertical bar as separator. Thus we need a bit of more complex AWK hackery.

```
awk '{gsub(/[;]/," ");printf "%s %s ",$1,$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/\|\|\|/) {gsub(/\|/," ");printf "%s %s",$(i+1),$(i+5);break} } printf "\n"; }' testData.txt
```

To put the above code into scripting form,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

{ 
  gsub(/[;]/," ");
  printf "%s %s ",$1,$2; 
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
     if($i~/\|\|\|/) {
        gsub(/\|/," ");
        printf "%s %s",$(i+1),$(i+5);
        break
     } 
   } 
   printf "\n";
}
```

Put that into a file, call it `myScript.awk` or anything, add exec permissions with`chmod +x myScript.awk` and give it input file as argument

Sample run:

```
$ chmod +x dataExtract.awk
$ ./dataExtract.awk testData.txt                               
2 41620CSQ=G missense_variant
```

Side note: in the question you said `missense_variant` is 4th field, but actually that's 5th field in the example you've posted.I've adjusted accordingly

**Edit as requested in comments:**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

{ 
  gsub(/[;]/," ");
  printf "%s\t%s\t",$1,$2; 
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
     if($i~/\|\|\|/) {
        gsub(/\|/," ");
        printf "%s\n" $(i+5);
        break
     } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Ah . . . simple fix . . . Just add `printf "\n" ` outside the for loop . . . I'll fix that up in a sec

Comment: Well CSQ=A is the first field after the `|||` part. Didn't you ask for first and fifth field after the `|||` ?

Comment: Also, `10642CSQ=A ` need to be spaced out to `10642 CSQ=A `.  I'll add a space to first `printf` statement

Comment: Yes, possible `missense_variant` is the fifth field, so that's the `$(i+5)` part.  If you want to get rid of `CSQ=A` remove the `$(i+1)` part , and change `printf "%s %s"` to `printf "%s\t"` . I'll make a small edit again in a sec

Comment: OK . . . now i really gotta go. Good night !